# Why table in first div is affecting content position in second div?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put content in two adjacent div elements but I have table in first div which is affecting vertical position of content in second div.

Here is my HTML file

```css
    .homepage{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;}

    .userarea {
 width: 50%;
    display: table-cell;}

    #area1{
 background-color: pink;}

    #area2{
 background-color: red; }

    #rgttop{
 background-color: blue;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
 <title>Welcome</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="beauty.css">
    </head>
    <body >
    <div class="homepage">

    <div class="userarea" id="area1">

 <table width="100%">
 <tbody>
 <tr>
 <td width="50%">
 <div >
  <p>Person 1: ABCD</p>
  <p>Person 2: QWRT</p>
  <p>Person 3: TYUI</p>
  <p>Person 4: FGHJ</p>
  <p>Person 5: BNMV</p>

 </div>
 </td>
 <td width="50%">
 <div >
  <p>Person 1: ABCD</p>
  <p>Person 2: QWRT</p>
  <p>Person 3: TYUI</p>
  <p>Person 4: FGHJ</p>
  <p>Person 5: BNMV</p>

 </div>

 </td>

 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
    </div>

    <div class="userarea" id="area2">
 <div id="rgttop">
  Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello
 </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

First div is id = area1 and second div id = area2

The Problem is with div with id = rgttop.

Can somebody explain why it is shifted and how to position it correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just need to float `.userarea`.

```css
.homepage{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.userarea {
 width: 50%;
    float: left;
    display: table-cell;
}

#area1{
 background-color: pink;
}

#area2{
 background-color: red;
}

#rgttop{
 background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
 <title>Welcome</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="beauty.css">
    </head>
    <body >
    <div class="homepage">

    <div class="userarea" id="area1">

 <table width="100%">
 <tbody>
 <tr>
 <td width="50%">
 <div >
  <p>Person 1: ABCD</p>
  <p>Person 2: QWRT</p>
  <p>Person 3: TYUI</p>
  <p>Person 4: FGHJ</p>
  <p>Person 5: BNMV</p>

 </div>
 </td>
 <td width="50%">
 <div>
     <p>Person 1: ABCD</p>
  <p>Person 2: QWRT</p>
  <p>Person 3: TYUI</p>
  <p>Person 4: FGHJ</p>
  <p>Person 5: BNMV</p>
 </div>

 </td>

 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
    </div>

    <div class="userarea" id="area2">
 <div id="rgttop">
  Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello
 </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: mixing float wirh tables?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using tables where appropriate. Nor is there anything wrong with floating divs. Nothing is being mixed here.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding **vertical-align: top;** to #area2 style?